# Resize multiple rows in 3 D array

Tags: python

I am trying to resize a 3D array using Jupyter ( # examples, width, height) of data to a new 3D array with (( same # examples, new width, new hight). Could you please help how to do it using cv2 package?.

a has a 10000 image with size 128,150
a.shape
(10000,128,150)

I want to change the resize each image inside a to have a new dimension
(10000,64,300)

I tried to use cv2 in Jupyter but I failed as it is not able to take each image separately and resize it and give me the new array of 10000 images with new dimensions for each image

```
Data=pd.read_csv('Mixedimages.csv',header=-1)

a=Data.values

a.shape

(10000, 150, 128)
```

## method 1

```
import cv2

for i in range(10000):

b = cv2.resize(a[i,:,:], (1000,64, 300), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

## method 2

```
 from scipy import misc

  newim= misc.imresize(a.T, (128, 150),interp ='nearest')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by :

## method 1

```
a_Resized=[]

n=10000
for i in range(n):
    img=a[i,:,:]
    a_Resized.append(cv2.resize(img, (64, 300), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST))
    i=i+1
```